# Functions as method

Tags: php, html, function

I have a function that returns an array. After that I create another function what is use the first. This is work fine, I tested with `var_dump()`, but when I call the second function in other page I got `NULL` back? Here is my code:

1st function

```
function get_blogs()
{
  global $kapcsolat;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE b_aktiv ='1' ORDER BY b_datum DESC";
  if($eredmeny = mysqli_query($kapcsolat,$sql))
  {
    if($db = mysqli_num_rows($eredmeny)>0)
    {
      while($sor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eredmeny))
      {
        $tomb[] = $sor;
      }
      mysqli_free_result($eredmeny);
      return $tomb;  
    }
    else
    {
      $tomb[] = null;
      return $tomb;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo'nem sikerült csatlakozni';
  }
}
```

Here the second

```
function public_blog()
{
  $blogok = get_blogs();
}
```

And this is the code how i include the second function:

```
include 'admin/functions.php';
public_blog();
```

But when i call public_blog i cannot use $blogok variable. I mean give back NULL. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second function neither returns anything nor sets up the value of the global variable (and `$blogok` is local to the function it's created in), hence it's practically useless. Perhaps you meant this:

```
function public_blog()
{
  return get_blogs();
}

... 
$blogok = public_blog();
doSomethingElseWith($blogok);
```

Still, I see little purpose here for that intermediate function, unless you intend to do something with results of `get_blogs()` in it.

As a sidenote, what's purpose of this?

```
$tomb[] = null;
return $tomb;
```

Here a single-element array is returned from a function (if no rows are found). But this result is not considered empty, and will probably introduce bugs in other parts of your code. It's better to replace this with either `$tomb = array();` or `$tomb = null`, depending on how it's used.

Comment: This work! Thank you. I just thinking why i can't create a simple procedure what is tore result of functions...
Okay, and what if i want return more array? I need to use return array?

Comment: You can always create another function; the true point is, why do you need it. If you want to collect some results of different functions, yes, you can return them like this: `return array(first_fn(), second_fn());`

Comment: Yes, that is why i need. Thank very mutch!

Answer (score 0):

Your first functioon is `return`ing some data to the second function.

In your second function you are just assigning the returned data from the first function into a variable and nothing else is happening.

So what you need is another `return` statement:

```
function public_blog()
{
  $blogok = get_blogs();
  return $blogok;
}
```